# Load a TPackage from the Grid

Tags: pascal

I have two Library Packages. Both are defined as process nodes in my main project. How do I use them? That is, how can I load my process node packages and create the windows on the Grid?

Comment: BTW the Development Environment is Power++ and I am use Pascal++ as Dialect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use CreateFromProcessNode constrcutor like this:

```
var p: TPackage;
begin
  p := TPackage.CreateFromProcessNode('YourLibName');
```

TPackage handles automatically the Grid traffic, and you can use your forms directly as if they were included in your project. For example:

```
  p.CreateForm('FormName').Show;
```

BTW: A) TPackage is documented in the Quick Help and B) You would get a faster answer if you post your question in the Power++ Question forum at gridplusplus.com.